# How to calculate the partition function of a given distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, signal-processing

As noted in [A FULL BAYESIAN APPROACH FOR INVERSE PROBLEMS](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0111123.pdf), let $ y = Ax + n$, where $y$ is a $m$ dimensional signal and $n$ is white Gaussian noise with precision $\beta$, so we have:
$$
 y|x, \beta \sim N(Ax, \beta^{-1}I) \Rightarrow p(y|x, \beta)=\frac{1}{Z(\beta)}exp(-\frac{1}{2}\beta\left\lVert y-Ax \right\rVert^2)
$$

The partition function is $Z(\beta) = (\frac{2\beta}{\pi})^{m/2}$ as claimed in the paper *and my question is why this is the case?*

I know $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y|x,\beta)dy=1 $, but I reach to different result: $Z(\beta) = (\frac{2\pi}{\beta})^{m/2}$. 
Thanks.

Comment: so is it the integral for obtaining $Z(\beta)$ the issue or how we arrive that $Z(\beta)$ is that particular integral?

Comment: Indeed calculation of the integral is my problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you have to integrate over $\mathbb{R}^n$, because $y$ and $x$ are multi-dimensional right?

Then $Ax$ is just a translation, so by a change of variables you can see that $Z(\beta)$ does not depend on $Ax$, so you can set $Ax=0$.

So you have to solve $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\frac{1}{2} \beta ||y||^2}dy$$ 
You can use Fubini and the well-known fact that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2}dy=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you Augustin, but the final result must be related to $\beta$ as indicated in the source paper. (I'll edit the question and cite the paper as soon.)

Comment: Yes, $Z$ is a function of $\beta$, and the first integral I wrote is also a function of $\beta$. You'll have to use the value of the gaussian integral, but not directly.

Comment: I try to solve it, but a $\sqrt{\beta}$ appears in denominator. And applying the assumption of independence leads to multiplying $m$ such results that give $Z(\beta)\varpropto\beta^{-m/2}$ instead of  $Z(\beta)\varpropto\beta^{m/2}$. :(

Comment: Are you sure about that? I find $Z(\beta)=\left(\frac{2\pi}{\beta}\right)^{m/2}$, so your result would be correct.

Comment: I reach to the same result but in the source paper the result is $Z(\beta) = (2\beta/\pi)^{m/2}$!